# Regular Expressions in Python - match all that does not contain... (App Engine)

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

Just started using App Engine's webapp framework, but I can't figure out what's wrong with this:

My URL structure is set up to where any pages are prefixed with /x/ . For example..

> http://site.com/x/my_account
>
> http://site.com/x/profile
>
> http://site.com/x/admin

etc etc....

Now I want to be able to match *NOT* prefixed with /x/ to be handled by another handler. This will be a user's page.

EX:

```
http://site.com/user1

http://site.com/user2
```

Here's my WSGI Application

```
        application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ('/((?!/x/).)*$', Profile.ProfileMainHandler),
      ('/x', Misc.MainHandler),
      ('/x/', Misc.MainHandler),
      ('/x/videos', Videos.VideoHandler),
      ('/x/videos/add', Videos.VideoAddHandler),
              # etc etc, many more to list...
```

Why is this not working? The /x/etc handlers work fine, but instead of anything else going to Profile.ProfileMainHandler, it doesn't match anything.

As always thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
'^/(?!x/|x$).*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs are matched in order, from first to last. Simply add a `.*` regular expression after all URL patterns that match `/x`.